# Convert even odd index in array to key value pairs in json using jq

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I'm trying to use jq to parse Solr 6.5 metrics into key value pairs:

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 7962
},
"metrics": [
"solr.core.shard1",
"QUERY./select",
"solr.core.shard2",
"QUERY./update"
...
]
}
```

I'd like to pick even odd entries in metrics array and put them together into a single object as key value pairs like this:

```
{ 
   "solr.core.shard1": "QUERY./select",
   "solr.core.shard2": "QUERY./update",
   ...
}
```

Till now, I am only able to come up with:

```
.metrics | to_entries | .[] | {(select(.key % 2 == 0).value): select(.key % 2 == 1).value}
```

But this returns an error or no results.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. I feel like the answer is probably in the map operator, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '[ .metrics as $m | range(0; $m | length; 2) 
      | {($m[.]): $m[(. + 1)]} ] | add' jsonfile
```

The output:

```
{
  "solr.core.shard1": "QUERY./select",
  "solr.core.shard2": "QUERY./update"
}
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#range(upto),range(from;upto)range(from;upto;by)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of the ability to do $m[.]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helper function which makes the solution trivial:

```
# Emit a stream consisting of pairs of items taken from `stream`
def pairwise(stream):
  foreach stream as $i ([]; 
      if length == 1 then . + [$i] else [$i] end;
      select(length == 2));
```

From here there are several good options, e.g. we could start with:

```
.metrics
| [pairwise(.[]) | {(.[0]): .[1]}]
| add
```

With your input, this produces:

```
{
  "solr.core.shard1": "QUERY./select",
  "solr.core.shard2": "QUERY./update"
}
```

So you might want to write:

```
 .metrics |= ([pairwise(.[]) | {(.[0]): .[1]}] | add)
```

Comment: thanks, but the above solution worked for me for a more complicated case.